# How can I use 'flutter_screenutil' and 'monarch' together?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, monarch

I am trying to use Monarch into my new project.

```
Widget paid() => HistoryItem(Paid(
                orderDate: '2023-11-10',
                subscriptionType: 1,
                orderId: '3YMU5SCEP57H',
                orderPrice: 10000,
                orderProduct: 'Vitamin C'));
```

However, it doesn't seem work with flutter_screenutil.

It shows

> 'LateInitializationError: Field '_minTextApdapt@1810084504' has not been initialized. See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

`14.sp` doesn't work and `ScreenUtil().setSp(14)` also doesn't work.

So, How can I fix this issue? enabling minTextAdapt doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrapped the widget with ScreenUtilInit().

```
Widget paid() => ScreenUtilInit(
    child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: HistoryItem(Paid(
                orderDate: '2023-11-10',
                subscriptionType: 1,
                orderId: '3YMU5SCEP57H',
                orderPrice: 10000,
                orderProduct: 'Vitamin C')))));
```